# JavaFX ChoiceBox doesn't show initial value

Tags: user-interface, javafx, enums, properties, binding

I have a factory method that gives me a ChoiceBox with a bidirectional binding to an enum property. The choice box works as expected, except that it doesn't show the initial value set in the property constructor. Instead the choice box shows up initially as blank, not showing any value. What's wrong?

Here's an MRE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChoiceBoxMRE extends Application {

    private ObjectProperty<Table> table = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Table.BIG);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().add(getChoiceBox(table));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T extends Enum<T>> ChoiceBox<T> getChoiceBox(ObjectProperty<T> objectProperty) {
        ChoiceBox<T> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox.getItems()
                .addAll(objectProperty.getValue().getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants());
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(objectProperty, choiceBox.valueProperty());
        return choiceBox;
    }

    enum Table {
        BIG, SMALL;
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: faintly remember that's a bug fixed recently

Comment: ... found it: [JDK-8087555 ChoiceBox: uncontained value not shown](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087555), fixed in fx15

Comment: Thanks - I edited my question with an MRE. Not quite sure if the bug fits the problem - in my case the selected value is an element of the backing list, isn't it?

Comment: Follow-up question: I'm running this on JDK 1.8, which I believe was the last long-term version to include JavaFX, mainly to make it easier for my client. If the bug is really the problem, is there any way to get the fix without going to the the current version of JavaFX, which has to be installed separately?

Comment: ahh .. well, yeah, naturally nothing is shown if nothing selected - why did you think it would? So no, the issue isn't related.

Comment: @kleopatra I thought that when you instantiate an enum property with some initial value and then bind the property to the choice box, the box would automatically show that value as the selected value. Isn't that how it's supposed to work? For example when I instantiate a string property with some initial value and bind it to a text field, the text field automatically shows the value without having to set the text property explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is a bug or not, but there is a simple workaround: simply select the value prior to binding it:

```
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(objectProperty.get());
```